# flatten import statements using bash script

Tags: xcode, bash, import

I have a source code from internet having import statements like 
    `#include "os/c-api/il2cpp-config-platforms.h"` 
    `#include "ab/cd.h"`
    `#include "ef/gh/ij/kl.h"` etc
in many places. 
I need to change all such import statements in all files to 
    `#include "il2cpp-config-platforms.h"`
    `#include "cd.h"`
    `#include "kl.h"` etc,

because import statements with path is not working in xcode for some reason. Can this be done easily in bash script? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you intend to do :

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.cpp' -exec sed -i -E 's#(^.*)(\/)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.h)#\#include "\3#g' {} \;
```

Im assuming your files have extension **cpp** but you can change that. Also, the **-i** in sed will change the file contents in place.

For security, make a backup of your files BEFORE running this.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Preferably: `find . -type f -name '*.cpp' -exec sed -i '\|^[[:space:]]*#include "os/c-api/| s|os/c-api/||' {} \;` as it would only affect actual `#include` statements and ignore comments and other in-line matches that are not includes.

Comment: Actually even the pattern selection I wrote will also modify `#include` statements within multi-line comments. It would be possible to exclude multi-line comments from the initial selection, but you'd need different sed commands to exclude multi-line comment blocks from the selection.

Comment: sorry for less clarification. i have edited my question a little. Change in question is that there are many such import statements with different file name and path, all of which i dont know. So simple sed command won't work

Comment: @user3247895 Can you try now? I have edited my answer